# Compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+\left(f_4(x)\right)^2}$ where $f_{i+1}(x)=x-\frac{1}{f_i(x)}$ and $f_0(x)=x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am very confused and intrigued by this integral.
According to WolframAlpha, it says that the answer is $\pi$.

I find this hard to believe because the function inside the parenthesis is simplified as

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{dx}
{1+\left(
x-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{x}}}}  
\right)^2}
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{dx}{1+\left(
x-\frac{x^3-2x}{x^4-3x^2+1}  
\right)^2}.$$

Does Glasser's Master Theorem still apply?? If so, how???

If not, how is this solved? Or is there a secret trick I don't know about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it does. We have for all $x$,
$$
x^4 - 3x^2 + 1 = \left(x^2 - \frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(x^2 - \frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right) = \left(x - \sqrt{\frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)\left(x + \sqrt{\frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)\left(x - \sqrt{\frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)\left(x + \sqrt{\frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}}\right).
$$
It proves that the polynomial $x^4 - 3x^2 + 1$ has $4$ distinct real roots $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4$. By the primitive elements decomposition theorem, there exists unique constants $\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3,\beta_4$ such that for all $x \notin \{\alpha_i,1 \leqslant i \leqslant 4\}$,
$$
\frac{x^3 - 2x}{x^4 - 3x^2 + 1} = \sum_{i = 1}^4 \frac{\beta_i}{x - \alpha_i}.
$$
The last hypothesis to verify to use Glasser's master theorem is that all the $\beta_i$ are non-negative. In fact for all $i$, we have,
$$
\beta_i = \lim_{x \rightarrow \alpha_i} \frac{(x^3 - 2x)(x - \alpha_i)}{x^4 - 3x^2 + 1}.
$$
Let $\alpha_1 = \sqrt{\frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{2}}$, $\alpha_2 = \sqrt{\frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}}$, $\alpha_3 = -\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_4 = -\alpha_2$.
\begin{align*}
\beta_1 & = (\alpha_1^3 - 2\alpha_1)(\alpha_1 + \alpha_1)(\alpha_1 - \alpha_2)(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)\\
& = 2\alpha_1^2(\alpha_1^2 - 2)(\alpha_1^2 - \alpha_2^2)\\
& > 0,
\end{align*}
because $\alpha_1^2 < \alpha_2^2$ and $\alpha_1^2 < 2$. Similarly, we can use the fact that $\alpha_2^2 > \alpha_1^2$ and $\alpha_2^2 > 2$ to prove that $\beta_2 > 0$. By a parity argument, we have $\beta_3 = \beta_1 > 0$ and $\beta_4 = \beta_2 > 0$. We can apply Glasser's master theorem and,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1 + \left(x - \frac{x^3 - 2x}{x^4 - 3x^2 + 1}\right)^2} \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1 + x^2} \, dx = \pi.
$$

Comment: HOLY HELL, SICK!!!

Comment: Bravissimo ! I deleted my junk answer (I had fun with it). Cheers :-)

Comment: Apologies to hijack your answer, but I've just read [Glasser master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem). What is preventing one from doing $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\frac{dx}
{1+\left(
x-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{x}}}}  
\right)^2}
=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\frac{dx}
{1+\left(
x-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{x}}}  
\right)^2}
=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\frac{dx}
{1+\left(
x-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{x}}  
\right)^2}
=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\frac{dx}
{1+\left(
x-\frac{1}{x}  
\right)^2}
=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\frac{dx}
{1+x^2}=\pi?$$

Comment: Thanks everyone ^^. @Benjamin Wang, when you use it, you have to replace all $x$. It would work for example with $x - \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x - \frac{1}{x}}$, which would become after a first use of this theorem $x - \frac{1}{x}$, and then $x$. But I don't think you can say anything with $x - \frac{1}{x - \frac{1}{x}}$ directly.